# Full example of Message Broker in Lagom

Tags: lagom

I'm trying to implement a Message Broker set up with Lagom 1.2.2 and have run into a wall. The documentation has the following example for the service descriptor:

```
default Descriptor descriptor() {
return named("helloservice").withCalls(...)
  // here we declare the topic(s) this service will publish to
  .publishing(
    topic("greetings", this::greetingsTopic)
  )
  ....;
}
```

And this example for the implementation:

```
public Topic<GreetingMessage> greetingsTopic() {
return TopicProducer.singleStreamWithOffset(offset -> {
    return persistentEntityRegistry
        .eventStream(HelloEventTag.INSTANCE, offset)
        .map(this::convertEvent);
  });
}
```

However, there's no example of what the argument type or return type of the `convertEvent()` function are, and this is where I'm drawing a blank. On the other end, the subscriber to the MessageBroker, it seems that it's consuming `GreetingMessage` objects, but when I create a function `convertEvent` to return `GreetingMessage` objects, I get a compilation error:

```
Error:(61, 21) java: method map in class akka.stream.javadsl.Source<Out,Mat> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: akka.japi.function.Function<akka.japi.Pair<com.example.GreetingEvent,com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.persistence.Offset>,T>
  found: this::convertEvent
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
  incompatible types: akka.japi.Pair<com.example.GreetingEvent,com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.persistence.Offset> cannot be converted to com.example.GreetingMessage)
```

Are there any more more thorough examples of how to use this? I've already checked in the Chirper sample app and it doesn't seem to have an example of this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you pasted tells you exactly what `map` expects:

```
required: akka.japi.function.Function<akka.japi.Pair<com.example.GreetingEvent,com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.persistence.Offset>,T>
```

So, you need to pass a function that takes `Pair<GreetingEvent, Offset>`.  What should the function return?  Well, update it to take that, and then you'll get the next error, which once again will tell you what it was expecting you to return, and in this instance you'll find it's `Pair<GreetingMessage, Offset>`.

To explain what these types are - Lagom needs to track which events have been published to Kafka, so that when you restart a service, it doesn't start from the beginning of your event log and republish all the events from the beginning of time again.  It does this by using offsets.  So the event log produces pairs of events and offsets, and then you need to transform these events to the messages that will be published to Kafka, and when you returned the transformed message to Lagom, it needs to be a in a pair with the offset that you got from the event log, so that after publishing to Kafka, Lagom can persist the offset, and use that as the starting point next time the service is restarted.

A full example can be seen here: https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-java/blob/a32e696/bidding-impl/src/main/java/com/example/auction/bidding/impl/BiddingServiceImpl.java#L91

Comment: Thanks; I've been poring over the auction example application you provided and it's been helpful (even though it's using the `taggedStreamWithOffset` instead of `singleStreamWithOffset` (which, to be honest, may be what I want anyway).

The part I was missing was the argument to `convertEvent`; for reasons, I was assuming that I was messing up the return type, even when I had the return type correct and that led me astray.

Again, thanks for the help!